# One to many mapping ConstraintViolationException in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables,Theater and Shows, which are joined by one to many mapping.I m trying to perform collection persistence as follows.

```
public class Theater 
{

    private int theaterId;

    private String theaterName;

    private List<Shows> shows;
    //getters and setters
}
public class Shows{
private int showId;
    private String showType;
    private int theaterId;

//getters and setters
}

SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session s = sf.openSession();
Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
Theater th = new Theater("iNox");
th.setTheaterId(4);

List<Shows> shs = new ArrayList<Shows>();
shs.add(new Shows("noon"));
shs.add(new Shows("Drama"));
th.setShows(shs);
s.save(th);
t.commit();
s.close();
```

xml mapping

```
<class name="hibernate.Theater"
            table="theater">
        <id name="theaterId"
            column ="theater_id">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id> 
        <list name="shows" table = "shows" cascade = "all" inverse = "false">
            <key column="theater_id" />
            <index column="show_id"/>
            <one-to-many class = "hibernate.Shows"/>  
        </list>   
        <property name = "theaterName" column = "theater_name" />
    </class>      

    <class name="hibernate.Shows"
            table="shows">
        <id name="showId"
            column ="show_id">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id> 
        <property name = "showType" column = "show_type"/>
        <property name = "theaterId" column = "theater_id"/>  
    </class>
```

adding relevant logs here

```
12:19:43,435 DEBUG EntityPrinter:114 - Listing entities:
  12:19:43,435 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - hibernate.Shows{showId=4, showType=Drama, theaterId=0}
  12:19:43,435 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - hibernate.Theater{theaterName=iNox, theaterId=4, shows=[hibernate.Shows#3, hibernate.Shows#4]}
  12:19:43,435 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - hibernate.Shows{showId=3, showType=noon, theaterId=0}
  12:19:43,442 DEBUG SQL:109 - insert into sakila.theater (theater_name, theater_id) values (?, ?)
  Hibernate: insert into sakila.theater (theater_name, theater_id) values (?, ?)
12:19:43,445 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [iNox]
  12:19:43,445 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [4]
  12:19:43,446 DEBUG SQL:109 - insert into sakila.shows (show_type, theater_id, show_id) values (?, ?, ?)
  Hibernate: insert into sakila.shows (show_type, theater_id, show_id) values (?, ?, ?)
12:19:43,447 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [noon]
  12:19:43,447 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [0]
  12:19:43,447 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [3]
  12:19:43,448 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:139 - could not execute statement [n/a]
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

based on logs,I guess theaterID(foreign key referred from theater table) is being generated properly(theaterID = 4) by auto increment.But,while adding corresponding shows,theaterID is used as 0. Can anyone point me to the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was trying for bi-directional association and had forgotten to include many-to-one mapping for theater in Shows class.Also,as suggested by The N,
replacing theaterID with Theater reference was required.

Added following mapping

```
<many-to-one
            name="theater"
            cascade="all"
            column = "theater_id"
            class="hibernate.Theater"/>
```

also found that `th.setTheaterId(4);` should be removed as theaterId is auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

In Shows Pojo you have defined threaterId as int, however it should be an object of Threater pojo.

In hibernate, if you want to use O2m relationship you must have to define the same in pojo.

So, for that you will have to modify you Shows pojo as

```
public class Shows{
private int showId;
private String showType;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="theaterId")
private Threater theater;

//getters and setters
}
```

It works for me. Please try

Comment: well...for me theaterId is the foreign key in Shows table,so I thought of using it(instead of Theater object).Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: In your pojo you have defined threatId as simple int variable which should be object of Threater class [as I mentioned] instead. In case of FK.